# Passing data from one function to another in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, machine-learning, p5.js

So I am using P5, and ML5 and I am working with them in React, so it kind of makes me jump over some hurdles to get things working.

I am trying to get the label name, to draw on the webcam. 
I can get the console.log to log the label name in the gotResults function, but I am not sure how I would go about using this to get it to work outside of gotResults..

Still new to coding so forgive me :)

```
    import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import p5, { VIDEO } from 'p5'
import ml5 from 'ml5'


const Webcam = props => {
    const myRef = useRef();
    const [label, setLabel] = useState([
        { label: 'Starting Label', confidence: 0 },
    ]);

    useEffect(() => {
        let myp5 = new p5(sketch, myRef.current)
    });


    const sketch = (p) => {


        let mobilenet;
        let cam;
        let classifier;
        let thumbUpRight;
        let thumbDownRight;
        let thumbUpLeft;
        let thumbDownLeft;
        let trainButton;
        // let label = '';


        const modelReady = () => {
            console.log('Model is ready!');
        }

        const videoReady = () => {
            console.log('Video is ready!');
        }

        const whileTraining = (loss) => {
            if (loss == null) {
                console.log('Training Complete')
                classifier.classify(gotResults)
            } else {
                console.log(loss)
            }
        }



        const gotResults = (error, result) => {
            if (error) {
                console.error(error);
            } else {
                // console.log(result)
                setLabel(result);
                classifier.classify(gotResults);
            }

        }



        p.setup = () => {
            p.createCanvas(640, 550);
            cam = p.createCapture(VIDEO);
            cam.hide();
            p.background(0)
            mobilenet = ml5.featureExtractor('MobileNet', modelReady)
            classifier = mobilenet.classification(cam, videoReady)

            thumbUpRight = p.createButton('Up Right');
            thumbUpRight.mousePressed(function () {
                classifier.addImage('thumbUpRight');
            })

            thumbDownRight = p.createButton('Down Right');
            thumbDownRight.mousePressed(function () {
                classifier.addImage('thumbDownRight');
            })

            thumbUpLeft = p.createButton('Up Left');
            thumbUpLeft.mousePressed(function () {
                classifier.addImage('thumbUpLeft');
            })


            thumbDownLeft = p.createButton('Down Left');
            thumbDownLeft.mousePressed(function () {
                classifier.addImage('thumbDownLeft');
            })


            trainButton = p.createButton('Train');
            trainButton.mousePressed(function () {
                classifier.train(whileTraining);
            })
        };


        p.draw = () => {

            p.background(0);
            p.image(cam, 0, 0)
            p.fill(255);
            p.textSize(32);
            p.text(label[0].label, 10, 530);
        }

    };

    return (
        <div ref={myRef}>

        </div>
    )
}

export default Webcam;
```

EDIT: So the error is something to do with the state resetting, and re-rendering the webcam, and everything on each call to ML5? I am guessing, it's like redrawing each time it hits the ML5 api.. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that these re-renders are happening because the `classifier.classify(gotResults)` function will execute many times and there you're updateting the state using `setLabel(result)` which will cause a re-render evetime it's being called. You can comment that and check if it's the cullprit. If it is, then you should shallow compare `results` with the `label` and only update the state `setLabel(result)` if these objects are different:

#### Shallow compare `result` with `label` before updating the state:

```jsx
const gotResults = (error, result) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(error);
  } else {
    if (!areEqualShallow(label, result) {
      setLabel(result);
    }
    classifier.classify(gotResults);
  }

}

function areEqualShallow(a, b) {
  for (var key in a) {
    if (a[key] !== b[key]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

If that's not the culprit of these re-renders, then you should check you `useEffect` hook. I don't know if you do it intentionally, but having a `useEffect` hook without any arguments, it will have that hook execute on each render.

> [**Using the Effect Hook**](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)
>
> **Does useEffect run after every render?** Yes! By default, it runs both after the first render and after every update. (We will later talk about [how to customize this](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects).) Instead of thinking in terms of “mounting” and “updating”, you might find it easier to think that effects happen “after render”. React guarantees the DOM has been updated by the time it runs the effects.

#### This hook will run on each render:

```
useEffect(() => {
  let myp5 = new p5(sketch, myRef.current)
});
```

#### Add an empty array to the end of the `useEffect` hook to run it only once:

```
useEffect(() => {
  let myp5 = new p5(sketch, myRef.current)
}, []);
```

**UPDATE**

To update the label on your existing P5 object, you'll have to use [`redraw`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/redraw). You have to create an effect hook on the `label` state variable which it will be called when the `label` changes:

```jsx
// Set a P5 ref so you can use it again
const p5Ref = useRef();

// Change the initial hook to set the p5Ref
useEffect(() => {
  p5Ref.current = new p5(sketch, myRef.current);
}, []);

// This effect will run only when the whole label object is updated,
// not just when a label.<prop> is updated
useEffect(() => {
  // I'm not sure if that's going to work,
  // you'll have to test and see how to force redraw using the P5 returned object properly

  if (p5Ref && p5Ref.current) {
    p5Ref.current.redraw();
  }
}, [label]);
```

Of course this hook will not trigger if you just change a `label` value due to object reference, so you'll have to create a new object when you update the `label` using the `setLabel` like this:

```jsx
const gotResults = (error, result) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(error);
  } else {
    // Create a new object so we'll get the update effect hook to trigger on label change
    setLabel({ ...result });
    classifier.classify(gotResults);
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome whatever you had said at first broke some stuff, or I probably didn't refactor my code correctly but fixing the useEffect hook, had fixed the webcams from re-rendering, but now my label wont change with each api call it makes? Like the label stays as starting label.

Comment: Also thank you for the depth answer, really helps learn a lot! :)

Comment: The label got updated because there was a re-render loop using that `useEffect` hook creating as new p5 object on every render and thus getting to update the label. You should find how to update the existing p5 object using the returned `myp5` variable maybe, thus you'll update the existing object than creating a new on on each render.

Comment: Would you happen to know how to do that off the top of your head so ha.. Sorry, I am not sure how I would go about doing it. I am so new to hooks, and react in general.

Comment: There is a React P5 package that you should be using [react-p5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-p5) instead of directly using the P5 so I think your code will need to refactor on that. You must **force** a [P5 redraw](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/redraw) after you change that label, I will update my answer with a potential solution, but I'm not sure if it's going to work for you, you need to try and refactor it, but again I'm suggesting you switch to [react-p5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-p5).

Comment: I had seen that there was a package but I read an article that said I would have more flexibility doing it this didn't think it would cause me so much trouble, thank you for giving it a shot anyways. I'll try to refactor with react-p5 if it doesn't work out.

Comment: I haven't used P5 that much, maybe you do have more flexibility, but I bet that everything can be done using it. I have updated the answer with some potential redraw code when tha `label` gets updated. I'm not sure about the `redraw` method, you'll have to test it and see how it's working to force a redraw. Other than that, that's the proper way to handle state updates in React hooks, using `useEffect`. Pay attention to object reference immutability.

Answer (score 2):

Can you have `label` in state?

```
const [label, setLabel] = useState('')
```

and

```
const gotResults = (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
        console.error(error);
    } else {
        // console.log(results)
        setLabel(results[0].label)
        mobilenet.predict(gotResults)
    }
}
```

Then, you can use `label` anywhere in the `Webcam` function.

Comment: Okay, so that didn't work aha it caused the Webcam to be re-rendered on the site till it crashes.  Also the text was still not drawing onto the webcams even if they where re-rendering.